# Why is my text all black and not auto indenting in emacs

Tags: emacs

In one of my files, everything was working fine. Things were being color-coded and auto-intending perfectly for me. When I started a new file to work on some other code, I noticed that the text was black and nothing was being indented for me. I tried asking google a whole bunch of questions like, "how to turn on auto-indent for emacs" and "how to change the theme color." I tried following suggestions online, but none seem to work. Is there a way I could reset my settings to default?

Comment: Bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: There's not really enough information here.  What's different about the files that are fine and the file that is problematic?  Are the "good" files *still* good?  I'm guessing the "bad" file is a  different file type and consequently a different major mode in Emacs, but that's just a guess -- please provide more information.  Also run `emacs -Q` and test the files -- if the problem does not exist there, then you can be sure it'll be something in your own config.

Comment: I am new to using emacs, so I have no idea how to do that. Any new file I create doesn't have color anymore nor does it indent.

Comment: Sorry for not adding enough information. This has nothing to do with me trying to run a code. Things aren't being color-coded for me anymore and there is no auto-indent. The files that are "good" are no longer good. When I open those files, the colors and indents are still there from before I was having this issue, but if I try adding on to it, nothing gets color-coded or indented for me. I am also having the same problem when making a new file to edit in, nothing gets color-coded or indented. I am fairly new to this so those are the only issues that I was able to notice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a name for the file I forgot to put .cpp at the end. Sorry for the waste of time and Thank you to everyone who tried to help me.